# Write Hex NDEF Message, into NFC tag

Tags: android, tags, hex, nfc, ndef

Can we write the whole NDEF message, into an NFC Tag, using Hex presentation?
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Understanding_NFC_Data_Exchange_Format_(NDEF)_messages

Comment: How does presentation really have anything to do with writing to a tag?

Comment: An NDEF message is in bytes. So how you chose to present/encode the bytes, does not matter. Can you represent bytes as hex? Yes. Also in all other working encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this myself but:
Should it not be possible to create the hex message, use toBytes / toByteArray or what not then use the

```
 NdefMessage(byte[] data)
```

Construct an NDEF Message by parsing raw bytes.
Considering that hex is just a representation of bytes this should work out for you.

More info
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html